# Casting sender to IBAction as id or specific class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I see two approaches to handling sender objects in IBAction statements. The first looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
 UIButton*someButton=(UIButton*)sender;
 //do something with someButton.tag or whatever
 }
```

Another seems easier:

```
 -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender{
  //do something with sender.tag or whatever
  }
```

I generally opt for version 2. Any particular reason to prefer one style over the other, if you know that only a button will be sending to this method?

I can see where version 1 is good if *anything* can be a sender, like a button, or switch or slider, etc. But if you are looking for `UIButton` properties like `tag` it won't make much difference if your sender is not a `UIButton`. So version 2 seems a lot more straightforward.

Just thought I'd see if I'm missing an obvious reason to prefer version 1.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference, but sometimes you're using the same action for many different objects and using the tag to select which one of them is the right one, so it really depends on your needs. Interface Builder just doesn't care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no problem using the second version. I usually use the second version, only using the first version if the sender may be more than one type of object. Then, if the method needs to know what type of object, the method can query the sender before casting the sender to a particular type.

Even more frequently I find no need to access the sender, so I just use:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
  // Do something.
}
```

Comment: I agree with this one. Unless you have a need to respond back, just leave the sender off.