# actual difference between - (IBAction)pushClear:(id)sender and - (IBAction)pushClear:(NSButton)sender

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa, xcode4

When I link buttons to the source code (.h file in this case) and select `NSButton` as type it Xcode will write:

```
- (IBAction)pushClear:(id)sender;
```

as far as I understand it should be

```
- (IBAction)pushClear:(NSButton)sender;
```

am I right, or just somewhat confused? If I link s.th. from within the iOS Interface Builder, everything seems to do what it should.

so will I have to fix these things by hand? Or is it ok the way it is (in the end, every things working fine. Just don't want to step into problems down the road.

**EDIT:**

Is there some sort of performance issue by just using?

```
- (IBAction)pushClear:(id)sender;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting sender to IBAction as id or specific class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256989/casting-sender-to-ibaction-as-id-or-specific-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set type like this:

```
- (IBAction)pushClear:(NSButton *)sender;
```

if you are sure, that only `NSButton` objects will send this actions.

If you are not sure, than you may leave:

```
- (IBAction)pushClear:(id)sender;
```

and inside of this method check that `sender` is kind of class `NSButton`.

Comment: so the easiest would be to just set all as (id), right? or is there some sort of performance issue behind it? thanks. - (IBAction)pushClear:(id)sender; –

Comment: The easiest way in some cases is to set `(NSButton *)` in others `(id)`. Try both of them. You can start from `(NSButton *)` i think =)