# what is the different between identifier id and class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

id is the type of the object; the type could have been `NSArray` * or  `NSString` *, for example.
Class can either be `NSArray` * or  `NSString` * or other object.

I can use them like follow

```
- (void)wantWriteAction:(id)sender {
}

- (void)wantWriteAction:(Class)sender {
}
```

I want to know the different between them.In what conditions can't use id?what condition can't use  Class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256989/casting-sender-to-ibaction-as-id-or-specific-class

Comment: id can be anything and can respond to any message in the system but class can respond to particular. id is generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` represents an instance of any class. `Class` represents any class-- not an instance, but the class itself.

So `id` could be a specific instance of `NSString` or `NSArray`. You can call instance methods on it-- those which are shown with a `-` in the documentation, like `-length` or `-stringByAppendingFormat`. If the `id` is an `NSString` then its value might be `@"foo"`.

`Class` could be the `NSString` class or the `NSArray` class. You can call class methods on it-- those which are shown with a `+` in the documentation, like `+stringWithFormat`. If the `Class` is `NSString` (note, not **an** `NSString`, but **the** `NSString` class) then it has no string value, because it's not a string. It's a class.